# Nesting blocks in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to be able to call a 'completionHandler' block from inside another completionHandler block (called after an asynchronous URL request). This however results in the application crashing with the following message (I'm using Zombie objects):
`*** -[CFRunLoopTimer hash]: message sent to deallocated instance`

Using instruments I was able to find out that the problem is due to the block being deallocated but I can't figure out how to keep it retained for long enough. Is it because I'm calling the block from another asynchronous block? My code is below (MyCompletionHandler returns `void` and takes `void`):

```
-(void)requestWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request withCompletionHandler:(MyCompletionHandler)serverCompletionHandler{

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        // do stuff…


            if (serverCompletionHandler) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            serverCompletionHandler();
         });
    }];
}
```

However this code is called through another method which supplies the `serverCompletionHandler` parameter (could this be the problem?).

So for example, the above method would be called by this method:

```
-(void)createAndSendRequestWithCompletionHandler:(MyCompletionHandler)serverCompletionHandler{

    NSMutableURLRequest* request = //..
    [self requestWithRequest:request withCompletionHandler:serverCompletionHandler];
}
```

Instruments shows that a block is either released or deleted (I assume the block I am calling) which would explain the deallocated object being called.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
The code for the timer (which seems to be deallocated) is:

```
if ([timer isValid]) {
    [timer invalidate];
}
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(createAndSendRequestWithCompletionHandler:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

The confusing thing is the code worked fine until I added the `completionHandler`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No thats not a problem you can acess the block within another block.I think problem is that you are already on  mainQueue (`[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]`) and you again try to `getMainQueue` on mainQueue.As `sendAsynchronousRequest` uses `NSRunloop` of queue it gets deallocated when you again ask for main queue as you are already on main queue.You can check if you are already on main queue just call `serverCompletionHandler` else `dispatch on mainqueue`.You can skip this check in this case as you are sure your are `main queue` and can just call `serverCompletionHandler()`

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    // do stuff…


if([[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] isEqual:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]]){ //check for main queue
    if (serverCompletionHandler) {
            serverCompletionHandler();
      }
}
else{
    if (serverCompletionHandler) {    if not than dispatch on main queue
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ //No need to do that
        serverCompletionHandler();
     });
}

}];
```

**EDIT**:Thanks of edited code.As you are using

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(createAndSendRequestWithCompletionHandler:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Now as you are not passing `completionhandler` so by doing this `createAndSendRequestWithCompletionHandler:` timer passes itself to your `serverCompletionHandler`.
So `serverCompletionHandler` itself contains `timer` object not any `block` object.If you try to `NSLog` `serverCompletionHandler` in `requestWithRequest` you will find it is timer object.Now when dispatch_async tries to call `serverCompletionHandler` as it is not block it will crash.

Write these two lines in `createAndSendRequestWithCompletionHandler`

```
NSLog(@"serverCompletionHandler obnj %@",serverCompletionHandler );
NSLog(@"class %@",NSStringFromClass([serverCompletionHandler class] ));
```

**EDIT 2**

if you really want to pass the completion handler than pass in `userInfo` of timer object.Use below code

```
#import "YourViewController.h"
typedef void (^MyCompletionHandler)(void);

@interface YourViewController ()
{
    NSTimer *timer;
}
@end

@implementation YourViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if ([timer isValid]) {
        [timer invalidate];
    }

    MyCompletionHandler com = ^{
        NSLog(@"Hi this is completion handler");
    };

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(createAndSendRequestWithCompletionHandler:) userInfo:@{@"serverCompletionHandler":com} repeats:YES];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)requestWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request withCompletionHandler:(MyCompletionHandler)serverCompletionHandler{

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        // do stuff…


        if (serverCompletionHandler) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                serverCompletionHandler();
            });
        }

    }];
}


-(void)createAndSendRequestWithCompletionHandler:(NSTimer *)timerObj{

//    NSLog(@"serverCompletionHandler obnj %@",serverCompletionHandler );
//    NSLog(@"class %@",NSStringFromClass([serverCompletionHandler class] ));


    //get completion handler from `userInfo`
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [self requestWithRequest:request withCompletionHandler:timerObj.userInfo[@"serverCompletionHandler"]];
}


@end
```

Comment: agree, but why would you check to see if you're on the main queue when you know you're on it?  the first param to sendAsynch... specifies the queue where the completion handler will be called.

Comment: In case you are on another thread and operating this `sendAsynchronousRequest` on some other queue as it is not usual to operate this method on `main queue`.We can skip this check in this case

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions however it still deallocates the block. Im trying to find out the object that is being deallocated (through the memory address) but so far I'm not having much luck.  


The `createAndSendRequestWithCompletionHandler` method is also called by an NSTimer with `userInfo:nil` if that is important.

Comment: Ok so it seems like the timer is the one being sent the message (the addresses match) but is deallocated. What could be the reason? The timer is an instance variable in a singleton so I don't see why it would be deallocated. Also, it seems to be on the second fire that the crash happens (this may not always be the case..)

Comment: Need to look code.One reason is `timer` also operate on `runLoops` so may be something happens that timer runloop deallocates.But i am not sure until i see code

Comment: have you find the problem??

Comment: @codester No, the app still crashes. Instruments seems to blame it on a block (makes sense, only started crashing after I added the blocks) but the deallocated object matches the timer (the address..)

Comment: @LlamaGoingNorth you are not passing the `serverCompletionHandler` in timer. `serverCompletionHandler` from where it comes ???

Comment: @codester that was the problem, but how can I pass a nil to the `serverCompletionHandler` instead of the `NSTimer` object? Is this possible?

Comment: do not do anything just `createAndSendRequest` and remove parameter and `timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(createAndSendRequestWithCompletionHandler) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];` notice `:` remove `:` from calling

Comment: BTW why you are passing `serverCompletionHadler` if you do not want to use it.

Comment: If you really want to pass completion handler i have passed in userInfo have a look edited answer

Comment: @codester thank you so much for your help - all working now. It was there so I could call the method manually without a timer and with a completionHandler if I needed to.